# No such table: while compiling Delete Table ... but I'm not deleting any table

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm getting this error message No such table ... while compiling DELETE FROM .

Here's my problem: I don't ever delete any table!

I've tried to run through my code, and here is what happens:
DataSettings.java 
1.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

1. It then jumps to DatabaseHelper.java

   ```
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
   ```

   Question: why? why would it jump to DatabaseHelper.java. What is there in my code that tells it to do that.

It goes back to DataSettings.java. 
   The next line is:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_data_settings);
    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
```

Then it crashes. Telling I have no such table feature_test_table: while compiling DELETE FROM X.

I'm baffled. What is going on? I've gone through and I've tried to erase anything that  has the word delete in it. But I still get this error message. Could this be due to upgrading to Kepler?

2 links for sample code: http://textuploader.com/1l0s

http://textuploader.com/1l0c

Comment: Add your class declaration so we can see if you are extending any class.

Comment: That's this part "class MyClass ... {"

Comment: @jeremyjjbrown done, the second time.

Comment: still missing, you must be extending some kind of Activity

Comment: @jeremyjjbrown. yes. sorry, I had to erase my link because I put the wrong thing up. NOW, I'm done.

Comment: post your whole logcat output

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the constructor of SQLiteOpenHelper in this line of DatabaseHelper.

```
super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
```

SQLiteOpenHelper [requires you to implement an onCreate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) method but you have not. You should start there by overriding that method in DatabaseHelper.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include enough of the class, but I have implemented onCreate(): http://textuploader.com/1l0c